# prediction and imputation of missing values using a panel data model (R)

Tags: r, model, panel

I have a panel dataset, which is unbalanced. I created a pooled model and now need to predict and input the missing values of the dataset. How can it be done?
Here is a printscreen of my data: https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/1366x440q90/661/RAH3uh.jpg
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all it looks like you have a too broad question in here. If you're really asking about how you should predict values for your spreadsheet (i.e cells: Z6,AA6,...,AM22,...); yes you have a HUGE questions =]. Just a hint, in your following questions, you should be more specific, like: I have THIS data related to *Households* in *Belarus*. I've searched about predicting models for that and tried **XPTO1** and **XPTO2**. How can I decide which one is better?

So, what I really mean here is that predicting is not exactly a function like SUM, that you can apply to your data and that's it. Prediction is a whole discipline, with a bunch of methods that should be tested to different cases. For example, to predict the Z6 cell in your data, you should to ask yourself what other data can contribute to infer data missing information? In some cases the simple average value for the past 5 years will be enough, in some other, a lot more should be considered.

I recommend you to first take a look at some basic material that covers simple models, like linear models, play with them, try to understand the accuracy of obtained predictions... That will finally solve your problem, or will at least help you to ask the community more "answerable" questions.

One last tip: there is a new SO's sister Q&A community that may be more appropriate to ask questions about prediction models: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Good luck.